# Is there a function for iterating through POSIX environment variables?

Tags: c++, c, environment-variables, posix

I've just been reading about the [complexities of `environ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) and in particular how thread-unsafe it is due to it being legal to [assign to it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/exec.html) to replace the entire environment.

This in mind, is there any kind of an API for iterating through all current environment variables which doesn't use the static `environ` array directly?

To be clear, I'm aware of [`getenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html), [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html) and friends (the less said about [`putenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/putenv.html) the better IMO) - these only allow recovery of specific variables, not iterating through them all.

I've also written plenty of code that iterates through `environ` directly. But it strikes me that in any sensible multi-threaded application, the only sane way to use the environment is either insert code as early as possible in `main()` to slurp it into an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or similar and only ever use it from there; or to just treat it as totally immutable and hope none of you linked libraries do otherwise.

So I was wondering if there was any safer interfaces defined as part of POSIX, or perhaps platform-specific, of which I was unaware?

Comment: well other than the shopping list question of is there a library to do x... you could focus on cpp if you want something like a map, because there isn't a C map structure in the standard library...

Comment: Indeed, in pure C you'd need to use an allocated array of allocated `char` buffers instead - but it's the same principle of taking a copy which is what I meant. In terms of shopping list, perhaps - but POSIX APIs are usually rather better than the awful mess that is the environment handling. In particular there are usually reentrant variants of functions where needed, but I suppose the required behaviour of being able to modify `environ` rather hampers any efforts to wrap access in a nice API and still remain compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a multithreaded application, the only sensible way to use the environment is to treat it as read-only. If you need to modify it, you should do so in the program initialization phase, before starting up any threads.

Since the purpose of the environment is to communicate from the environment to the application, treating the environment as read-only should not be a problem. Consistent with this use case, there is no standard interface for iterating over the environment other than the use of `environ`, and that cannot be used safely in a multithreaded application unless the application is committed to not modifying the environment.

As far as I know, no standard library function modifies the environment (other than `setenv` and `putenv`), and IMO no sane library would do so either.

It is recognized that it is occasionally necessary to modify the environment, either to introduce default values or as part of the initialization sequence for a forked child. In the former case, the modifications can normally be performed as above, prior to starting threads.

The latter case is tricky in a multithreaded application, but in any event, it is easy enough to modify the environment only in the child (i.e. after the call to `fork()` and prior to calling `exec*()`. Alternatively, a completely new environment could be constructed and supplied to a version of `exec()` which accepts an environment argument.

In short, using the environment as a surrogate for global variables is even worse (imho) than using global variables in the first place. However, using it for the purpose for which it was invented -- configuration of child processes by their parent -- should not cause problems.

---

After an interesting discussion in comments, it seems worth adding a couple of notes.

First, many standard (and non-standard) library functions *read* the environment. That's particularly convenient for debugging, but it is also used for a number of configuration options, including execution path search, locale, console window size, time zone, etc., etc., etc. (There's a long but incomplete list in the Base Definitions volume of the Posix standard.)

Since `getenv` cannot be used safely in multithreaded code unless it is known that no concurrent modifications can be made to the environment, it seems reasonable to prohibit standard library functions from modifying the environment (other than the interfaces designed for such modifications). Posix does not include this prohibition, as far as I know, but it does require all interfaces to document their use of the environment and I don't believe I've seen any interface other than `putenv`, `setenv` and `unsetenv` which are documented to modify the environment. On the whole, I believe it is completely reasonable (and even necessary) to assume that the environment will not be modified in multithreaded code after threading is initiated.

Of course, it is legitimate to modify the environment in single-threaded code, or in multithreaded code prior to initiating threads. But best practice dictates that only one of two possible modification mechanisms be used:

1. The `setenv` (and `unsetenv`) interface.
2. Direct assignment of `environ` to a different array, in which any strings present in the original `environ` have been copied into memory managed by the application.

The use of `putenv` cannot really be advisable, but it is acceptable provided it is not mixed with the other two possibilities above.

Again, Posix does not provide restrictions, guidelines or advice (other than preferring `setenv` to `putenv`), so take the above as my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. This more or less tallies with my understanding, but the environment API is so particularly awful (even for POSIX!) I thought I must be missing something. The way that you can assign to `environ` - but that later calls to, say, `setenv()` detect this and copy it back... It's a memory management nightmare!

I typically use [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) for the latter problem you specify, and construct the environment explicitly. I find it more convenient than fork/exec where I need to run external binaries.

Comment: @cartroo: generally, `setenv` does not do that, but at least one implementation did/does. But the provision is there in case the implementation wants to, and the reason it might want to is to solve (part of) the memory management issue. I agree that `putenv` is hideous; as the rationale explains (if you read between the lines), it's included because some historical unices had it while others had `setenv`, and the only possible conciliation was to include both. However, `setenv` is explicitly preferred. I stand by what I wrote: don't use the environment as a surrogate for global variables...

Comment: Yes, I certainly wasn't meaning to imply it was a good idea to use the environment for anything unless necessary, but the sad truth is that some old libraries may depend on them, especially for debugging. Sometimes it's useful to enable that programmatically. Re `setenv()` I think it surely *has* to copy in the case that application reassigns the whole of `environ`? Which is an explicitly supported way to replace the entire environment. Otherwise it wouldn't know the size of array that the user allocated.

Comment: Based on [this page](http://annotary.com/bookmarks/386822/posix-environ-copying) it seems it's legal to assign to `environ`, which would mean `setenv()` would have to implement the copying behaviour when adding new variables. [This page](http://annotary.com/bookmarks/386824/posix-setenv) indicates the behaviour of `setenv()` is undefined if `environ` has been assigned to, but that's issue 6 - looks like [issue 7](http://annotary.com/bookmarks/386827/posix-setenv-issue-7) made it more ambiguous. Confusing!

Comment: @Cartroo: Sure, lots of libraries depend on *reading* the environment, which is perfectly safe even in multithreaded code provided no attempt is made to modify the environment. Consequently, any modifications (to configure debugging options, for example) should be made prior to initiating threads. Posix doesn't say this, but it's not required of a standard to provide usage advice.

Comment: @Cartroo: There is another difference between issue 6&7. Issue 7 allows the use of setenv even after having replaced environ but adds the prohibition (in Base Definitions): "If the application modifies the pointers to which environ points, the behavior of all interfaces described in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 is undefined." This makes it easier for setenv to manage memory as long as putenv is not called; it can assume that the entire `environ` is either library-allocated strings or user-allocated strings. Thus it only needs to track `environ` to manage its own memory.

Answer (score 1):

> *"So I was wondering if there was any safer interfaces defined as part of POSIX, or perhaps platform-specific, of which I was unaware?"*

No one I'm aware of.

> *"But it strikes me that in any sensible multi-threaded application, the only sane way to use the environment is either insert code as early as possible in `main()` to slurp it into an `unordered_map` or similar and only ever use it from there; or to just treat it as totally immutable and hope none of you linked libraries do otherwise."*

This won't make anything *safer*, since you would need to update that map, if `setenv()` or `putenv()` was called from anywhere else (maybe from code not under your control).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, if you can't rely on all the code you link in to treat the environment as read-only then I think you're asking for trouble... As Rici says above, however, the libraries that modify the actual environment (as opposed to taking their own copy to pass to `posix_spawn()` or similar) should be few and far between!